# R ggplot2 aes argument

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I have a function:

```
vis = function(df, x){
p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x)) + geom_line(aes(y = v2))
p1
}
```

I have a data frame:

```
df = data.frame(v0 = c(1,2,3), v1 = c(2,3,4), v2 = c(3,4,5))
```

I want to generate plot: (1) v2 v.s. v0, (2) v2 v.s. v1.

So I tried:

```
vis(df, v0) // not work
vis(df, v1) // not work
vis(df, "v0") // not work
vis(df, "v1") // not work
```

Much appreciated any idea!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we are passing an unquoted string, then convert it to quosure and then evaluate (`!!`)

```
library(rlang)
library(ggplot2)#devel version

vis = function(df, x){
    x <- enquo(x)
    p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(!!x)) + 
                      geom_line(aes(y = v2))
    p1
}
```

If we pass `x` as strings, then replace `aes` with `aes_string`

Comment: @Hanbo the `!!` should also work.  You may need the dev version of `ggplot2`

Comment: I got an error **in !x : invalid argument type**  when I passed unquoted variable: `vis(df, v1)` Do you have some idea? Thanks!

Comment: @Hanbo This is implemented in the devel version.  Do you have the dev version.

Comment: `!!` works, when I used dev version ggplot2. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 5):

Another method using `quo_name` and `aes_string`. This does not require dev version of `ggplot2`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(rlang)

vis = function(df, x){
  x <- enquo(x)
  ggplot(df, aes_string(quo_name(x))) + geom_line(aes(y = v2))
}

vis(df, v0)
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can use the the name of the column:

```
df = data.frame(v0 = c(1,2,3), v1 = c(2,3,4), v2 = c(3,4,5))

vis = function(df, x){
  p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(df[,x])) + 
    geom_line(aes(y = v2))+xlab(x)
  p1
}
vis(df, "v0")
```